# Solve $e^x = 2x$ with algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, closed-form, elementary-functions

I’m trying to solve $$e^x = 2x.$$
I have already understood that there isn’t any solution when I plot both functions, but I would know how to get this conclusion by trying to solve it algebrically.
I got owned with:
$$\ln(e^x) = \ln(2x)$$
$$x\ln(e) = \ln(2x)$$
$$x = \ln(2x)$$
Then I don’t know how to continue.
I tried to pass it in WolframAlpha and other computation but the only thing it tell me that there is no solution.

Comment: it hasn't solution 'cuz their plots clearly indicate there is no intersection https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Be%5Ex%2C2x%7D

Comment: Yes but is it possible to prove it with algebra ? @janmarqz

Comment: maybe by contradiction

Comment: Ok i see, it seems difficult… thank’s @janmarqz

Comment: You can use $e^x \geq 1 + x + \frac12x^2$ for $x \geq 0$, and $e^x > 0$ everywhere (in particular, for $x < 0$).

Comment: I don’t see the link, how did you got the $$1+x+1/2x^2$$

Comment: Show that $2x < 1 + x + \frac12x^2$ everywhere, and $2x < 0$ for $x < 0$.

Comment: Ok thank you very much :) I will try to understand

Comment: Oh, I understand your confusion now.  Those are the first three terms of the Taylor series expansion of $e^x$.  For $x \geq 0$, all the terms are non-negative (and strictly positive for $x > 0$).

Comment: Thank you very much I think I understand now

Comment: I don't see an algebraic proof.  It's pretty easy to see that $f(x) = e^x-2x$ has its absolute minimum at $x = \ln 2$ and since $\ln 2 \lt 1, f( \ln 2) \gt 0$, so $f(x)$ has no zeroes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We see that $e^x=2x\implies x>0$. Because, $e^x>0,\thinspace \forall x\in\mathbb R$.

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}&e^x=2x,\thinspace x\in\mathbb R\\
\implies &x=\ln 2+\ln x, \thinspace x>0\\
\implies &e^u-u=\ln 2,\thinspace u=\ln x \\ 
\implies &\ln2+u≥u+1;\thinspace e^u≥u+1\\ 
\implies &\ln 2≥1 \\ 
\implies &e≤2 \\
&\text{A contradiction.}\end{align}$$

Comment: There are actually complex solutions using a product log function.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Yes, Lambert-W works.

Comment: Where is your second implication coming from?  Adding $u$ to both sides of the second equality doesn't get you there because $\ln 2 \lt 1$.

Comment: @Robert $\ln 2+\ln x=x\implies x-\ln x=\ln 2 \implies e^u-u=\ln 2$. Where is the error?

Comment: You've changed your second implication.  How do you know that $e^u \geq u+1$?  Doesn't that require use of the Taylor series?

Comment: @Robert I didn't change anything. I just added more details. Math SE has hundreds of proofs of this $e^x≥x+1$.  I think you know this.

Comment: My only point is that the request was for an algebraic proof, and I'm not sure there is an algebraic proof that this equality has no solutions.

Comment: @Robert I say again: You can find hundreds of proofs in Math. SE (algebraic proof has also been made) There is no need to proof again for this inequality.

Answer (score 1):

As I indicate in the comments, you can use the bounds

$$
e^x > \begin{cases}
0 & x \leq 0 \\
1+x+\frac12x^2 & x > 0
\end{cases}
$$

and

$$
2x \leq \begin{cases}
0 & x \leq 0 \\
1+x+\frac12x^2 & x > 0
\end{cases}
$$

The expression $1+x+\frac12x^2$ comes from the first three terms of the Taylor series expansion for $e^x$; all terms are non-negative for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: The use of a Taylor series makes it seem to me like not an algebraic proof, as was requested.

Comment: @RobertShore: One must have *some* definition of $e^x$.  It could just be the Taylor series itself, in which case there is no more direct route.  (I would say that is a very common definition, in fact—perhaps the most common.)  Another definition could be that it is the unique solution to $\frac{dy}{dx} = y, y(0) = 1$, in which case I believe there is no point to a "purely algebraic" solution, whatever that might be.  In some sense, the involvement of $e^x$ already implies a partly non-algebraic solution.

Comment: Or, alternatively, you could define $e^x$ as $\lim_n\to\infty \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$.  I don't happen to prefer this one, but if you use it, you can apply a generalized binomial theorem and recover the Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=e^x-2x$ then $f'(x)=e^x-2$ and it annulates only in $x_0=\ln(2)$.

Therefore $f\searrow$ then $\nearrow$ with a minimum in $x_0$.

The minimum $f(x_0)=e^{\ln(2)}-2\ln(2)=2-2\ln(2)>0$ so the function has no zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Making the problem more general, consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=e^x-kx$$ the solution of which being given in terms of Lambert function
$$x=-W\left(-\frac{1}{k}\right)$$ This solution is real only for $k \geq e$.

So, if $k<e$, assuming that you do not want to use Lambert function, let $xa+b i$ to make
$$e^x-k x=\Big[e^a \cos (b)-a k\Big]+i \big[e^a \sin (b)-b k\Big]$$ Cancelling the real part, we have
$$ e^a \cos (b)-a k=0 \implies b=\cos ^{-1}\left(a e^{-a} k\right)$$ Plugging it in the imaginary part leads to
$$g(a)=k \cos ^{-1}\left(a e^{-a} k\right)-e^a \sqrt{1-a^2 e^{-2 a} k^2}=0$$ which is difficult to solve using a numerical method such as Newton.

We can *approximate* the solution using a series expansion around $a=0$

$$g(a)=\left(\frac{\pi  k}{2}-1\right)- \left(k^2+1\right)a+\frac{3k^2-1}{2} a^2 -\frac{\left(k^2+6\right) k^2+1}{6} a^3 +\frac{15 k^4+10 k^2-1}{24}
   a^4 +O\left(a^5\right)$$ Using series reversion
$$a=t+\frac{\left(3 k^2-1\right) t^2}{2 \left(k^2+1\right)}+\frac{\left(-k^6+20 k^4-25
   k^2+2\right) t^3}{6 \left(k^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{\left(-15 k^8+245 k^6-511
   k^4+183 k^2-6\right) t^4}{24 \left(k^2+1\right)^3}+O\left(t^5\right)$$ where $t=\frac{\pi  k-2}{2 \left(k^2+1\right)}$.

Using it for $k=2$ as in your case, this would give as an *estimate*
$$a_0=\frac{-30391+23984 \pi +6144 \pi ^2-176 \pi ^3+439 \pi ^4}{187500}=0.762140\cdots$$ which would give $b_0=0.779407$.

If you want to polish the root of $g(a)=0$, using Newton method, the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_n \\
 0 & 0.762140 \\
 1 & 0.793950 \\
 2 & 0.794024
\end{array}
\right)$$ This will give $b=0.770112$.